# is using "require_once" in wordpress theme affect the speed ???

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, performance

I am working on a framework to make my workflow faster like a starter theme plus boilerplate. so one of main parts that will make the work faster is the plurality ...

I for example in function.php when I need to create new post type instead of writing a big block of code (130 line) for each new custom post type ... I moved the code to separated folder then I call it by

```
require_once( 'library/custom-post-type.php' );
```

in this way, I can have many ready custom post types as files and for each project, I can just add the file also for future maintenance instead of the scroll in very big 1000+ function file ... it will be a short file with a list of require_once and folder that has all the code in separated files

**MY QUESTION:**

- Does the require_once !! affect the speed of the website?
- when I should use it and when I should not
- whats the harm of overusing it to get a more arranged code?

Comment: This is perfectly normal, but you should use `get_theme_file_path()` instead, for better child theme compatibility. I guarantee you that whatever performance impact this has (which would be negligible) there'd be a billion other ways to optimise your code, whatever it is. Don't optimise prematurely.

Comment: in the index and other pages mostly they look like this

        <?php include(locate_template( 'templates/parts/Header.php' ));?>
        <?php include(locate_template( 'templates/parts/bloxImgs.php' ));?>
        <?php include(locate_template( 'templates/parts/bloxMsn.php' ));?>
        <?php include(locate_template( 'templates/parts/bloxVote.php' ));?>
        <?php include(locate_template( 'templates/parts/bloxFAQ.php' ));?>
        <?php include(locate_template( 'templates/parts/bloxBook.php' ));?>
        <?php include(locate_template( 'templates/parts/Footer.php' ));?>

Comment: I am trying to build a starter theme/boilerplate to make my workflow faster and better ... that why the main part is taking all the part put them in files for reusability and clean code

Comment: Look at any theme you find, including the defaults, they all do this. It's fine. It's perfectly normal PHP to spread code out over multiple files. Any performance impact is completely negligible. You should be using WordPress functions though, like `get_template_part()` and `get_theme_file_path()`.